# unable to find tessdata for Tesseract

Tags: python, git, pytesser

Hi I am new to python and tesseract. I am using anaconda distribution and trying to use pytesseract-ocr when I try to get the data from image it gives me following error:

```
tesseract imageSample1.jpg test.txt digits
// output 
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.01 with Leptonica
Error opening data file /anaconda/envs/_build/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

So first this there is no such `/anaconda/envs/_build/share/tessdata/` directory. I have anaconda3 folder. I downloaded end.traindata from git. but not sure where to put that data. Am I doing some thing wrong. Need some help. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Tesseract will search in /usr/share/tessdata first.

If you want tesseract to search somewhere else, you can do one of the following

- set the environment variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` to the path where you put your data.
- call tesseract with `--tessdata-dir=<pathToYourData>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing the command : tesseract from your command window , You should get an output like this :
[image: tesseract output]

If not then you should install any version of tesseract on your machine [tesseract download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/)

Note : for pytesseract to work you need to have tessearct installed into system.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for replay #csharpcoder. I have checked it. And it shows me all option related to tesseract.

Comment: better try reinstalling tesseract 3.2.0 fromthe link shared shoul resolve the issue